# Undefined id when trying to add an id dynamically in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

This a simple to-do list and I am trying to add an id in each `<li>` that is rendered. Each id should be named different (obviously) but similar name: "id0","id1","id2"...etc

The number comes from the directive `v-for="i in items"`

I do it like this:

```
<li :id="`id${i.id}`" v-for="i in items" :key="`id${i.id}`">
```

Complete code:

```js
 <ul class="item-list-ul">
        <li :id="`id${i.id}`" v-for="i in items" :key="`id${i.id}`">{{ i }}
          <div class="item-butons">
            <b-button class="done-btn" @click="strikeItem(i)" size="sm" variant="outline-dark">DONE!</b-button>
            <b-button class="delete-btn" @click="deleteItem(i)" size="sm"  variant="warning">Delete</b-button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

My `items` array:

```js
data () {
      return {
          items: ["five", "<li>", "should","be","rendered"]
        }
    }
```

But when I check in the console the names of the new dynamically created id´s of the `<li>` they just appear `idundefined` when in the case of having for example 3 `<li>` they should appear like this:

```
id0
id1
id2
```

However in the console there aren't any errors. It seems that the vue-html simply does not read a number in `${i.id}` but just undefined. Why?

Comment: Try replacing your interpolations with simple concats. For example, try replacing this: `id${i.id}` (removing the backquotes) with this: `'id' + i.id`. Also check if the objects in your `items` array contain an `id` attribute.

Comment: What does `items` look like?

Comment: @DavidWeldon A one-dimensional array of strings.

Comment: @Aryton: I was unaware of it, too, and even convinced that I had seen a video by Evan You himself talking about template literal support as a feature for the upcoming Vue 3, but as it turns out, template literals are already working in Vue 2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `items` is just an array of strings, then there is no `id` property available. The standard idiom in this case is to use the index like so:

```html
<li v-for="(i, index) in items" :id="`id${index}`" :key="index">
```

Alternatively, you could reshape your data to have ids like:

```js
[{ id: 0, text: 'foo' }, { id: 1, text: 'bar' }, { id: 2, text: 'baz' }]
```

That could be done as part of a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), for example. Note this would also require a few changes to your template.